# Issue setting the position of a popup

Tags: 7, views

I am using Views Popup module to display the popup in my views. I have an image field when clicked displays the popup. I added jquery script in my views field template file to set the position of the popup based on the mouse clicked position. I am able to set the position but for some reason the position of the displayed popup seems to be getting reset . I am guessing this is done by the module while setting the display to block.

Any idea how the position can be reset?

Comment: you have to change inside the module css file, use firebug to inspect the css file location and this is off-topic question because it's about css(position the popup)

Comment: The style is not coming from a css file. It is set as inline style to the popup window. I dont consider this as off-topic since my question is not on how to set the css and it is about the module implementation.